# Vm Ubuntu + xampp Vs C: windows + xampp

Tags: mysql

i have been going round in circles for days trying to figure this out..
i have c: windows and xampp working fine for years
i have needed to install ubuntu so i put it on a virtual machine successfully.
i need a database running on ubuntu, i have installed xampp maybe 10 times, each time different errors, they must be conflicting with the C drive xampp.
i then tried to point ubuntu localhost to C localhost. Got the address and loads and works fine in ubuntu from Firefox. When i try from the terminal errors, tried loading just mysql and apache, changing the hsot address, but the terminal only recognises the new mysql and not the new on.
i have really spent 70 hours on this, try all sorts of methods. Can someone please tell me what i am doing wrong and point me in the right direction.

Comment: Without *specific* examples of what you tried, together with the *actual* error messages produced, I think this is going to be very hard to answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have been trying to install Xampp for windows or Lamp for your version of Linux. Maybe this is because of your hurry in asking your question or my insufficient amount of English knowledge. Anyhow if I've comprehended your question correctly, you are trying to install Lamp without having errors in Linux. Linux systems come completely different from Windows environment in some cases. In fact, the Xampp version for Linux is called LAMP (Linux, Apache, Mysql, PHP). Because Linux's power is mostly gained via its command line environment you can go to the address below to find out how to properly install LAMP on your Linux.
[How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)